# Best free tool to take scheduled backup of MySQL from Windows which is installed on Linux server

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I have installed MySQL database in VM and planned to take a backup periodically and it can be monitored and executed from Windows Machine.
But when I searched I could not find any full version software to take backup and mysql version is 8

Please advice.

Comment: If it's on a VM then you can probably schedule snapshots via a task scheduler of sorts

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQLBackupFTP.

There is a free version that works quite well:
https://mysqlbackupftp.com/features/

Using MySQLBackupFTP you can also connect to your MySQL database through phpMyAdmin if you can't get the TCP/IP access running. That is probably the easiest way.

If you want to have email confirmations about the execution of the back up you would either need to move to a paid version after a while or you simply use GMail or some other email provider. Easy to set up - and using GMail for this (or some other provider of your own) keeps everything free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a regular dump, you can schedule a bash script in CRON to run [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) regularly. If you then need access to this dump on your windows machine you can just ftp the dump files across or access them via a samba share.